# Regular expression for match when in the middle of a sentence only

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regexp to match the standalone letters I and V only when in the **middle** of a sentence.

I'm using preg_match_all, as there could be multiple matches.

I am able to create multiple regexps if needed, i.e. if clearer it is fine to split things out rather than have a complex single regexp.

The string will never contain line-breaks - it's never a multiline.

Examples:

`Materialy I regionalʹnoĭ` **would** create a match, and capture `I`.

`Materialy V regionalʹnoĭ` **would** create a match, and capture `V`.

`V strane lʹdov` - would **not** create a match, because the V at the start of the sentence string.

`Materialy. V dvukh tomakh` would **not** create a match, because the V is at the start of a sentence, i.e. after a dot-space.

`John i Vladimir` would **not** create a match for the V, because the V is not standalone.

`John i Vladimir` would **not** create a match for the i, because the i is lower-case.

`V strane lʹdov - Materialy I regionalʹnoĭ` would capture **only** the `I`, because only that is in the middle of a sentence.

I've been trying various combinations of ^ (?: (?! [] and so on, but can't get this to work.

Comment: Do you want `'~(?<=\s)(?<![?!.])(?<![?!.]\s)[VI](?=\s)~'`? Or, to better handle spaces, `'~[?!.]\s*[VI](*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\s)[VI](?=\s)~'`? Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTIpYd/1).

Comment: do you need regex why not find ` I ` or ` V `

Comment: You should show what you tried, along with the result.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor - that seems to be working based on the demo, and I'm just trying to understand it now. Could you perhaps add that as an answer, so I can ensure you get the reputation score?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you really are a regex god!

Comment: The check is only able to take place in a regexp context - I can't use str* unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~[?!.]\s*[VI](*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\s)[VI](?=\s)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTIpYd/1)

If the number of spaces is normalized in the sentences, you may just use

```
'~(?<=\s)(?<![?!.]\s)[VI](?=\s)~'
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTIpYd/3)

**NOTE**: If you need to make it work on a multiple line text, then it may be safer to replace all `\s` with `\h`, to only match **horizontal** whitespaces.

**Details**

- `[?!.]\s*[VI]` - matches `?`, `!` or `.`, then 0 or more whitespaces and then a `V` or `I`  and
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - since we know these are not welcome skip this match and go on searching
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\s)[VI](?=\s)` - match `V` or `I` when surrounded with whitespaces.

Comment: your regex would still capture the `V` at the start of the line https://regex101.com/r/9Xz0ce/1

Comment: @N69S No, it is impossible [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/9Xz0ce/2) is the correct online demo. OP is not using the regex against a multiline text, but against standalone strings.

Comment: I should probably have noted that the string will never contain line-breaks - it's never a multiline.

Comment: @N69S If you need to match horizontal spaces, and make it work for a multiline text as at regex101, just replace all `\s` with `\h`. Just as I did in my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTIpYd/1).

Comment: Thanks again - this is all very impressive. Despite using regexps for many years, I'd not had experience with `(?<=` or `(*SKIP)` / `(*F)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how is `(?<=\s)(?<![?!.])(?<![?!.]\s)[VI](?=\s)` different than `(?<![?!.])\s([VI])\s`

Comment: @N69S It might be a bit redundant, but is different due to the `\s` consuming parts in the latter regex. `(?<![?!.])` can be removed since the expected char before `V` or `I` is a whitespace anyway.

Comment: Presumably the `[VI]` needs a capture around it: `([VI])`.

Comment: @fooquency What do you need to do with the match? A whole match regex is more generic. If you need to extract only then capturing is always a good idea, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so if i understand what your saying, this will be a good example too `(?<![?!.]\s)(?<=\s)[VI](?=\s)` removed the extra `negative LookBehind (?<![?!.])`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The I or V is captured and replaced with a token, so it does indeed have to be captured.

Comment: @fooquency Replaced? You only capture what you need to keep and you match and do not capture what you need to remove.

Comment: @N69S Yes, `(?<![?!.]\s)(?<=\s)[VI](?=\s)` is what  I posted (just the order of lookarounds is different, `(?<=\s)(?<![?!.]\s)[VI](?=\s)`, but that is not important).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple regex that satisfies your use cases.

```
preg_match('/.*[^\.]\h([VI])\h.*/', 'V strane lʹdov - Materialy I regionalʹnoĭ');
```

Comment: This is an inappropriate solution. 1) `.*` at the start will greatly decrease performance due to excessive backtracking especially with longer strings, 2) literal spaces  do not account for other whitespace chars, 3) if there are two or more spaces before `V` or `I`, the regex will fail, 4) `?` and `!` sentence end punctuation marks are not accounted for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did say it satisfies the use cases provided.

Comment: So, if `.+` matches all the use cases, does it mean it is OK?

Comment: it's a valid answer for the information provided. Thanks for the remarks anyway